# ImportError: cannot import name GLM

Tags: python, pymc3

I installed pymc3 from pip and was going through getting started 
http://pymc-devs.github.io/pymc3/notebooks/getting_started.html

Towards the end they use GLM -

```
from pymc3.glm import GLM
```

Which returns error "ImportError: cannot import name GLM"

I am able to import other modules of pymc3.glm. For eg this works-

```
from pymc3.glm import families
```

Comment: Do you use python3 or python2?

Comment: using python 2 .

Answer (score 1):

install the module with pip3

> sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3

use python 3
then it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your pip once through :

**pip install --upgrade pip**

or

**python -m pip install --upgrade pip**

Even if doesn't solve the problem, there might be some problem with the module's version for 3+. In this case, try to go back to a stable 2.7 version.